# /usr/bin/bash: g++: command not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, terminal, g++, mingw

Just started C++ in VS Code, and Im setting uo C++ with MinGW, Complier, extensions, debbuging etc.
I got stuck in a problem that i cant find a solution. After I finished the task.json:

```
        "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "echo",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                      "-g", "learn.cpp"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

After i typed Ctrl+Shift+B so it can show in terminal, it shows:

```
/usr/bin/bash: g++: command not found
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 127
```

I'll be thankful if u guys help me with this problem!

Thank u!!

Comment: @TedLyngmo Actually I don’t have an idea about the problem, that’s why I’m asking for help

Comment: I get that, but in the heading it looked like it couldn't find `/usr/bin/bash` (before I edited it).

Comment: @TedLyngmo can u help me with the problem?

Comment: Not really, sorry. I just wanted to tidy up the question so it becomes more clear for others who have worked with those tools. You could perhaps examine your `PATH` variable and check if there's a `g++` program in any of the directories. If no `g++` is found, `find / -name 'g++'` to search the whole computer for where it is and use the full path as `command` or add that path to `PATH` - but I'm sure there's a better way to set this up.

Comment: Where did you install mingw? Did you install g++?

Comment: I installe mingw from google, but i didnt install any g++...